# Is it possible to define a context for syntax rules?

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to define a syntax for a C-like language. Let's for the sake of simplicity it has only arithmetic expressions, variable declarations and blocks of statements:

```
type_synonym vname = nat

datatype aexp =
  IntConst int
| IntVar vname
| Plus aexp aexp
| Minus aexp aexp

datatype com =
  Skip
| Let vname aexp
| Seq com com
```

The syntax for variable declarations:

```
syntax
  "_let" :: "vname ⇒ aexp ⇒ com" ("let _ = _")

translations
  "_let v init" ⇌ "CONST Let v init"

term "let x = y"
```

The syntax for blocks of statements:

```
nonterminal stmts

syntax
  "_no_stmts" :: "stmts" ("")
  "_single_stmt" :: "com ⇒ stmts" ("_")
  "_stmts" :: "com ⇒ stmts ⇒ stmts" ("_; _")

translations
  "_no_stmts" ⇀ "CONST Skip"
  "_single_stmt x" ⇀ "CONST Seq x CONST Skip"
  "_stmts x xs" ⇀ "CONST Seq x xs"

syntax
  "_stmt_block" :: "stmts ⇒ com" ("{{_}")

translations
  "_stmt_block xs" ⇀ "xs"

term "{{}"
term "{{a}"
term "{{let a = x; let b = y;}"
term "{{let a = x; let b = y; c}"
```

I have to use double braces `{{` because single braces are used for sets.

For sure, I can use bold braces so they will not confilct with a syntax for sets. Or I can disable syntax for sets.

But is it possible to define something like a context for syntax rules? For instance if I enclose an expression into ```` ```c ... ``` ```` block then only particular syntax rules are used:

````
term "```c {let a = x; let b = y;} ```"
````

Comment: IIRC, this is not possible and the work-around is to define a do-monad (see for example https://github.com/lammich/isabelle_llvm/blob/2023/thys/lib/MM/MMonad.thy where instead of c, the syntax is doM {...})

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I've got how it works and added an example of syntax rules similar to do-monad rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it:

````
nonterminal stmt and stmts

syntax
  "_c_code" :: "stmts ⇒ com" ("```c _ ```")
  "_empty_stmt" :: "stmts" ("")
  "_single_stmt" :: "stmt ⇒ stmts" ("_")
  "_stmts" :: "stmt ⇒ stmts ⇒ stmts" ("_; _")
  "_block" :: "stmts ⇒ stmt" ("{_}")
  "_let" :: "vname ⇒ aexp ⇒ stmt" ("let _ = _")

translations
  "_c_code c" ⇀ "_block c"
  "_block (_empty_stmt)" ⇌ "CONST Skip"
  "_block (_single_stmt c)" ⇀ "c"
  "_block (_stmts c (_empty_stmt))" ⇀ "c"
  "_block (_stmts c (_single_stmt xs))" ⇌ "CONST Seq c xs"
  "_block (_stmts c (_stmts x xs))" ⇌ "CONST Seq c (_block (_stmts x xs))"
  "_let v init" ⇌ "CONST Let v init"
````

You can use `print_syntax` command to debug the grammar rules.

`_c_code` can be empty (`_empty_stmt`), can contain single statement (`_single_stmt`), or can contain a `;`-separated list of statements (`_stmts`).

A single statement can be either `let`, or `{ }`-block.

Some examples:

````
term "```c ```"
term "```c let a = x ```"
term "```c let a = x; let b = y ```"
term "```c let a = x; let b = y; let c = z ```"
term "```c { } ```"
term "```c { let a = x } ```"
term "```c { let a = x; let b = y } ```"
term "```c { let a = x; let b = y; let c = z } ```"
term "```c let a = x; { let b = y } ```"
term "```c let a = x; { let b = y; let c = z } ```"
term "```c { { { let a = x } }; let b = y; }; let c = z ```"
````